# How to bind dataset from XML to ItemSource in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I am trying to bind a dataset from XML to an `ItemSource` and do not get it right.

Here is the `.xaml` part:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgLogView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

And here is the code behind:

```
using (XmlLogfileStream logfileStream = new XmlLogfileStream(filename))
{
    // File contents to read
    // <LogInfo><Time>2015-03-14 17:01:43</Time><Message>Logging first time with XML in C#</Message></LogInfo>
    // <LogInfo><Time>2015-03-14 17:02:11</Time><Message>Logging first time with XML in C#</Message></LogInfo>
    // ...

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(logfileStream);

    dgLogView.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["LogInfo"].AsEnumerable();
}
```

A screenshot of the issue:
[image: issue screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by changing my code as follows:

```
using (XmlLogfileStream logfileStream = new XmlLogfileStream(filename))
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("LogInfo");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
    ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);

    ds.ReadXml(logfileStream);
    dgLogView.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
}
```